# $ \exists c \in( a, b) \text{ such that } f(c)=\max\limits_{x \in [a, b]} f (x) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I saw in a corrected.

if We have $ f $ continuous on $ [a, b] $ with $ f (a) = f (b) $ and $ f $ differentiable left and right at $ (a,b)$ can we say that 
$$ \exists c \in (a,b) \text{ such that }  f(c)=\max\limits_{x \in [a, b]} f (x) $$

or

$$ \exists c \in (a,b) \text{ such that }  f(c)=\min\limits_{x \in [a, b]} f (x) $$

**My thoughts:**

since $ f $ continuous on $ [a, b] $ then f is bounded on $[a,b]$, thus f must attain a maximum and a minimum. so 
$$ \exists c \in (a,b) \text{ such that }  f(c)=\max\limits_{x \in [a, b]} f (x) $$
and 
$$ \exists c \in (a,b) \text{ such that }  f(c)=\min\limits_{x \in [a, b]} f (x) $$

Thank you.

Comment: There might not _be_ a maximum, but in that case there will be a minimum.

Answer (score 4):

If $a=-1$,$b=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$ then there isn't a c in the open interval as the maximum is at the end points.